# File open/copy extremely slow after VM moved to new host

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I shut down and exported a Hyper-V VM from one host and imported it to another (did it with several actually). However only my 2 VMs still on 2008 are acting really odd. They are running Server 2008, and due to be upgraded so that is likely the route I will take, however I can't do that during work hours, or on a whim.

Here is what is happening. If I copy a simple 1 meg file it takes 30+ seconds to do so.

It isn't likely the VM queuing issue from Broadcom as this is an Intel 10G NIC, and iperf is pulling a full 900+ Mbps on my 1G NIC from the same server. Local disk IO seems great as even a larger 200MB file copies instantly (these are on an enterprise SSD). Other VMs moved that were running 2012 copy perfectly fine, it is just the 2 2008 boxes.

What has me stumped is why the iperf runs flawlessly but file operations don't. Any ideas the new host is 2019, the old one was 2012 r2.

Comment: I suspect this might be an issue with the Hyper-V Integration Services in the guest. The Hyper-V Integration Services updates aren't coupled with Windows Updates for Windows Server 2008 guests as they are with newer Windows Server versions. Check which version of the Hyper-V Integration Services are installed in the guest and update if needed.

Comment: I bet you are correct, it being 2008 SP2 however there is no easy way to do that it appears. I was able to just do an in place upgrade to 2008r2 then to 2012r2 and it works fine now. Not sure how I accept yours as the answer though.

Comment: Actually it turned out to be even easier, it was the configuration level. It was set to 5, and 2019 is 9. So shutting down the VM and upgrading the config level worked to solve the slowness as well. I'm sure the Integration Services could be problematic too so I'd accept either as the answer. If I could figure out how.

Comment: Mine was a comment, not an answer so it can't be accepted. I posted a comment rather than answer because I wasn't totally convinced I was on the right track but I wanted to offer something that might point you in the right direction. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I'll self answer here, thanks to joeqwerty for nudging me in the right direction. Changing the configuration level of the guest VM fixed the problem. To do so, shut down the VM, right click and choose Upgrade Configuration Version, then start VM.